How to force the app to open in custom "minimum width"
so i have my phone that is set to "minimum width of" 384dp (in developers options), what i want to do is to open my android studio app like if the phone had its minimum width of 478dp.
is there any way to do it besides to make a different type of layouts for different screens size? maybe to write a code in OnCreate?


Do you mean something like this? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/layouts/adaptive

No that is not what i am trying to figure out

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), QuantityListener {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val changeddp = 478
        overrideDensity(changeddp)
        //^^^^before setting the layout(in my case test2), change the width.
        setContentView(R.layout.test2)
        }
}
    private fun overrideDensity(changeddp: Int) {
        val resources = resources
        val configuration = resources.configuration
        val screenwidthPx = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels
        val newDensity = screenwidthPx.toFloat() / changeddp
        configuration.densityDpi = (newDensity * 160).toInt()
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
    }

